# Converting chr to numeric and still not able to take mean

Tags: r, type-conversion, mean

I am working with a dataframe from NYC opendata. On the information page it claims that a column, ACRES, is numeric, but when I download it is chr. I've tried the following:

```
parks$ACRES <- as.numeric(as.character(parks$ACRES))
```

which turned the column info type into dbl, but I was unable to take the mean, so I tried:

```
parks$ACRES <- as.integer(as.numeric(parks$ACRES))
```

I've also tried sapply() and I get an error message with *NAs introduced by coercion*. I tried convert() to but R didn't recognize it though it is supposed to be part of dplyr.

Either way I get NA as a result for the mean.

I've tried taking the mean a few different ways:

```
mean(parks[["ACRES"]])
mean(parks$ACRES)
```

Which also didn't work? Is it the dataframe? I'm wondering since it is from the government there are limits?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have NAs in your data. Either they were there before you converted or some of the data can't be converted to numeric directly (do you have comma separators for the 1000s in your input? Those need to be removed before converting to numeric).

Identifying why you have NAs and fixing if necessary is the first step you'll need to do.  If the NAs are valid then what you want to do is to add the `na.rm = TRUE` parameter to the mean function which ignores NAs while calculating the mean.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see any NAs or commas but I did notice that the numbers were rounded up so anyone less than 0 became 0. Do you have any advice to get the actual decimal number?

Comment: As you using as.numeric or as.int? Because you'll want as.numeric.

Comment: You're right I tried both, and int rounded, obviously. I am now using as.numeric. The NA's happen after I do as.numeric they aren't from the downloaded df. It must happen in the conversion but do not know why. I am going to some research. I appreciate your help and any other advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how ACRES is being loaded in (i.e., what data type is it?). If it's being loaded in as a factor, you will have trouble changing a factor to a numerical value. The way to solve this is to use the 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' argument in your read.csv or whatever function you're using to read in the data.